# retrieve nested data in laravel-eloquent

Tags: eloquent

i have 3 tables mainly
**users**
id, username
**roles**
id, name
**user_roles**
user_id, role_id
**permission**
id, user_id, activity
i am building api in laravel 8 and am new.
i want to build rest service which will return
user_id, username, roles.name

also i would like to return permission stored in permission table like json

```
{
 "user_id" : 1,
 "username" : "user1",
 "role" : "guest",
 "permissions" : [
   {
   "id": "1",
   "activity" : "create-user"
   },
   {
   "id": "2",
   "activity" : "update-user"
   },
 ]
}
```

how can i achieve above structure?

Comment: at first u need to learn how to query tables from database mysql/sql/mongo

Comment: I know SQL queries, how to do with laravel eloquent?

Comment: have a look at here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

Comment: is it not possible with eloquent?

Comment: u have to use some library for that to work like https://github.com/ShisunXia/Laravel-Elasticsearch-Query-Builder